# connecting winForm and mobile through AWS

Tags: ios, database, winforms, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am looking to build a windows Form application (c#) that essentially saves data (entered manually) and I want that data to show up on an iOS app that I also will be building. Curious what approach to take in terms of database/cloud. I want all data entered in the Winform app to be saved on the cloud (AWS).

I have no experience with using databases, but I was wondering if AWS can be a solution for me. What technology would I be using in AWS to essentially upload the information from my winForm app and push it down to the iOS app.

and any courses/material you recommend to learn that part (I already know how to build both winForm apps and iOS apps)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a managed GraphQL service to accept your incoming requests using AWS AppSync (https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/) and hook up data resolvers which take those incoming requests to query and persist in your DynamoDB database.

To setup and interact with a backend, this will guide you through provisioning the API with AppSync, DynamoDB table, installing AWS Amplify in your iOS app, and using the API plugin to make requests to AppSync: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/api

I'm not familar with winForm apps, but you would need a similar way to construct the GraphQL requests to hit your AppSync backend: https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client